# Getting param from Reset Password link (Express)

Tags: node.js, email, express, query-string, sendgrid

I'm implementing a reset password feature for users of my site. Once a verified, well-defined user signs up, a unique token is generated (specifically for this case), saved in the database, and included as a parameter in the querystring of the link included in the "Forgot password" email to the user. The user then checks their email, clicks on the link, and will be redirected to a view where they can redefine their password.

The main obstruction I am dealing with in this process is obtaining the unique token as a parameter from the link when the user clicks on that link in their email. I referenced the [official Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) and specified the route (which is activated in the email when the user clicks on it in their inbox to go to a view to reset their password), and wrote the following route to handle it:

```
usersRouter.route('/reset/passwordLoggedOut/:token') 
    .get(emails.resetPasswordForgot);
```

with the ensuing resetPasswordForgot() function (minified for your viewing convenience):

```
function resetPasswordForgot(req, res){
    const token = req.params.token;
    console.log(token);
    res.send(200);
}
```

Console.log(token) is currently showing up null when I expect it to contain the user password token.

Some more background information, I'm using SendGrid for all of my automated emails, Mailinator for testing the emails as the user, and here is what the route looks like when I hover over the link within the email. (I realize that the image is small and probably impossible to view without zooming in several times, but I wanted to include as much of the URL as possible)

[image]

Please let me know what I need to do to get the token param from the link in the email.

Answer (score 0):

You need access by the [query](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#req.query) attribute:

```
function resetPasswordForgot(req, res){
    const token = req.query.token;
    console.log(token);
    res.send(200);
}
```

Comment: req.query.token yields undefined and req.query is an empty object. After further inspection, I believe that either a.) the querystring is not being passed in properly or b.) SendGrid is modifying the link in a way that prevents the param from being accessed correctly.